# Dynamically added Link Button doesn't fire the on click event on the first click - C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am dynamically adding Link Buttons to my Gridview as seen below:

```
protected void addLinks()
{
    foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gvData.Rows)
    {
        if (gvr.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string itemNbr = gvr.Cells[1].Text;
            LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
            lb.Text = itemNbr;
            lb.Click += genericLinkButton_Click;
            foreach (Control ctrl in gvr.Cells[1].Controls)
            {
                gvr.Cells[1].Controls.Remove(ctrl);
            }
            gvr.Cells[1].Controls.Add(lb);
        }
    }
}
```

This addLinks() function is called in my gridview_RowDataBound event and the Page Load event if(isPostPack).

The problem is that when I click the link buttons, the genericLinkButton_Click event does **not** get fired on my first click. It causes a postback, and then if I click it again, or click one of the other Link Buttons, the genericLinkButton_Click event **is** fired.

How can I make sure the click event happens on my first click?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My condolences for having to bother with WebForms.

When using Webforms and dynamically creating controls you are required to assign an ID to the created control before adding the control to the tree in order for them to work properly. Otherwise they will have changing ID's during the pagelifecycle resulting in the described behaviour.

```
private int _runningIndex = 0;
protected void gvData_RowCreated(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string itemNbr = e.Row.Cells[1].Text;
        LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
        lb.ID = "btn" + (_runningIndex++).ToString();
        lb.Text = itemNbr;
        lb.Click += genericLinkButton_Click;
        foreach (Control ctrl in e.Row.Cells[1].Controls)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[1].Controls.Remove(ctrl);
        }
        e.Row.Cells[1].Controls.Add(lb);
    }
}
```

should be working.

Comment: Instead of your variable you can use `e.Row.RowIndex`.

Comment: I used this technique w/ @TimSchmelter 's suggestion (except gvr.RowIndex) in my original method -- which is called in RowDataBound and IsPostBack on PageLoad -- and it works now. Thanks

Comment: you're welcome. make sure to also upvote helpful answers. it helps visitors from google etc to find viable solutions

Comment: Thanks Andreas, I faced similar problem when added dynamic link buttons.
anyone who faces similar problem can try following:
1. Add **id**
2.runat **server**
3.causesvalidation **false**

Comment: @Dbl  I have assigned the ids to the controls as suggested by you. Still facing the issue of 'First click not working'.

Comment: @Pramod try adding it at an earlier point in page lifecycle (and try to switch away from web forms ... :< )

Answer (score 1):

`RowDataBound` is triggered only if the GridView gets databound, so when you call `gvData.DataBind()`. But dynamically created controls must be created again on every postback.

The most appropriate event to create controls dynamically in a `GridView` is [`RowCreated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcreated(v=vs.100).aspx) which is triggered on every postback. Note that you the GridViewRow's `DataItem` is `null` on postback. So you cannot access it's datasource as opposed to `RowDataBound`. But that seems not to be necessary anyway here.

Note also that you don't need to loop all rows in `RowDataBound` or `RowCreated` since these events are triggered *for every* row in the `GridView` anyway.

```
protected void gvData_RowCreated(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string itemNbr = e.Row.Cells[1].Text;
        LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
        lb.Text = itemNbr;
        lb.Click += genericLinkButton_Click;
        foreach (Control ctrl in e.Row.Cells[1].Controls)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[1].Controls.Remove(ctrl);
        }
        e.Row.Cells[1].Controls.Add(lb);
    }
}
```

Comment: He's calling the method on every postback through the Page.Load event.

Comment: I tried to implement this anyways, but it's not working. itemNbr is not returning any value, perhaps because the cells aren't filled yet in the RowCreated event? So without the text from itemNbr the LinkButtons aren't even being added to the GridView.

Comment: @AkramShahda: `Page_Load` is too late to add event handler for dynamical controls. Also, he mentions that the "addLinks() function is called in my gridview_RowDataBound event and the Page Load event if(isPostPack)". So it is not called from `Page_Load` but from `RowDataBound` which is triggered only if you databind the grid.

Comment: @JimVincec: why do you databind the gridview `if(isPostPack)` and not `if(!isPostPack)`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter The datasource for the gridview is a DataTable being created after a button click. After the datasource is created, that's where I call the gridview databind event. It's not being called in (isPostBack) or (!isPostBack)